# ProjectName-Swift issue - Can't find protocol declaration for 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm now using Swift class in my existing Object-C project.In my Swift class, I'm using CLLocationManagerDelegate. Everything works well. However, when ProjectName-Swift.h is generated, an issue in ProjectName-Swift.h file shows that **Can't find protocol declaration for 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'**. I tried to silence the issue by importing **CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h** in ProjectName-Swift.h. It worked. But after compiled a few times, **CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h** was gone because ProjectName-Swift.h is generated from my swift class. And the issue comes again.

ProjectName-Swift.h

[image: issue screenshot]
Here is my swift class (No issue here)

`import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@objc class SSDLocationHelper: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   func findUserLocation() { ... 
                           }`

Comment: show the code for import statement for CoreLocation

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke please see it

Comment: wait.. the code you've pasted is swift code.. while the screenshot is from an ObjC code... i meant the import CoreLocation code in the file with the error, which you mentioned in your question text "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h"..

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h" will go away automatically after compiled a few times since  ProjectName-Swift.h is generated from my Swift class...

Comment: just add @import CoreLocation to the ObjC file and then try setting the delegate

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke It is already imported by Xcode automatically. Though I can edit the file manually but it will gets erased after compiled by XCode since it is Xcode-generated file.

Comment: Have you tried adding `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` to YourProject-Bridging-Header.h?

Comment: @Andrew I did, but it doesn't make any sense because the file is auto-generated. When coed compiled several times, it will be erased.

Comment: No, I mean in your project's Swift bridging header. I'm not sure if it'll work though.

Comment: @Andrew I just tried. Doesn't work

Comment: @NicHuang Could you solve the issue? How? :)

Answer (score 21):

The solution is to import the framework in your project bridging header.

ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid this one doesn't work for me. The same error is still being reported.

Comment: I was getting a similar error (cannot find protocol declaration for 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate'). Adding "#import UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h" to my bridging header fixed it.